# grep number after matching word in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get available and free swap and trying to use `grep`.

Command `free -m` prints it as:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1823         147        1372           8         302        1485
Swap:           511           0         511
```

I know  how to get total swap:

```
free -m | grep Swap | grep -oP "Swap:\s+\K\w+"
```

But can't manage to get Used and free.  Could someone please help?

Comment: `free -m | awk 'NR == 3 {print $2}'` will print the total swap

Comment: Get it from `/proc/meminfo` instead. It's less likely to change in the future.

Comment: With ideas from that other guy and Socowi: `[[ $(< /proc/meminfo) =~ SwapFree:\ +([0-9]+) ]] && echo "$((${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/1024))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk. If row starts (`^`) with string `Swap:` print fourth column:

```
free -m | awk '/^Swap:/ {print $4}'
```

Output:

```
511
```

Answer (score 1):

In grep you could use `Swap:\s+\w+\s+\K\w+` for the second and `Swap:\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\K\w+` for the third number. But there is an even better (pure bash) solution:

```
[[ "$(free -m)" =~ Swap:' '*([0-9]+)' '*([0-9]+)' '*([0-9]+) ]]
total="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
used="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
free="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```